# jqQuery find cell value, if exists change cell, if not add new row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I'm trying to achieve is when a number/text in input into the code box it searches the table, if found increments quantity by one, if not found adds a new row counting the no column by one.

I already a some basic jQuery code.

```
<input type="text" style="width: 200px" id="code" name="code" />
<input id = "btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Release"/>
<table> <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Qty</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>4444</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>5555</td>
            <td>1</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>6666</td>
            <td>1</td>

        </tr>
  <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>7777</td>
            <td>1</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

edit: my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {

    var code = $("input#code").val()
    var table = $("table tbody");
    table.find('tr').each(function(i) {
      no = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(),
        productId = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text(),
        Quantity = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text();


      if (productId == code) { //see if product is in table

        Quantity = +Quantity + +Quantity; // increase qty
        alert('found' + Quantity); 

      } else {
        // Add new row
        alert('not found');


      }


    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you expecting the input box entry to match the "No" or "Code" to trigger the increment "Qty"?

Comment: sorry no, is just an ever incrementing number, i expect it to match on code to trigger an increase in qty by 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put together a [JSFiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/doLvp095/), and copied the JS code here. I tried to make it as beginner friendly as possible...

```
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(){
    numRows = $("tr").length;
    for(var i=1 ; i<numRows ; i++){
        var code = $("tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td:nth-child(2)").html();
        var qty = $("tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td:nth-child(3)").html();
        if(code == $("#code").val()){
            $("tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td:nth-child(3)").html(parseInt(qty) + 1);
            return true;
        }
    }

    $("tbody").append("<tr><td>" + numRows + "</td><td>" + $("#code").val() + "</td><td>1</td></tr>");
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Perfect!!! thanks a million also helps as you stated as i will be adding to this in the future. massive thanks.

Comment: Paul, what would i have to change if the table id was id="example" ? to keep this working, regards.

Comment: You wouldn't have to change anything, the table ID isn't referenced at all. You'll only run into problems with this if you have more than one table in your markup. If that's the case, then you'll need to prepend the table ID to the current jQuery selectors, like this: "tr" to "#example tr" or "tr:nth-child(i) td:nth-child(2)" to "#example tr:nth-child(i) td:nth-child(2)".

Comment: yes thats the case i will be using more than one table, i tied your solution before asking and it does not increment the qty, just appends a new row every time

Comment: sorry, fixed it, its working i was missing the numRows = $("tr").length;. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample code using jQuery. It took me like 10 minutes to figure out what you are trying to achive but I hope I understood you quite well:

HTML Side:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 200px" id="code" name="code" />
<input id = "btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Release"/>
<table> <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Qty</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>4444</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>5555</td>
            <td>1</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>6666</td>
            <td>1</td>

        </tr>
  <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>7777</td>
            <td>1</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and our JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var found = false;

    $("input#btnSubmit").on("click", function() {
        var search_val = $("input#code").val();

        $("tr").each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);

            obj.find("td").each(function() {
                if(parseInt($(this).html()) == parseInt(search_val))
                {
                    obj.find("td:nth-of-type(3)").html(parseInt(obj.find("td:nth-of-type(3)").html()) + 1);
                    found = true;
                }
            });
        })

        if(found == false)
        {
            $("table").append("<tr><td>"+($("tr").length)+"</td><td>"+search_val+"</td><td>1</td></tr>");
        }

        found = false;
    });
});
```

Here's JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f17gudfw/4/

Comment: thanks for your quick reply!!! in qty increment works fine, its just not adding a new row if its not in the table. Thanks in advance - danny

Comment: I forgot to do it. My bad sorry but I created a working version for you again :/